# assigning a metadata user via the sassrv account

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I have built a test harness on the STP server, that spawns unique sessions for each test run.  The problem I have now is that one of my tests requires the use of a metadata account (and my spawned sessions are running under the sassrv system account).

For info, the code snippet that spawns those sessions is below:

```
  /**
   * Execute all the backtest scripts and retain the logs
   */
  options sascmd='!sascmd';
  %local waitforlist;
  %do x=1 %to %get_attrn(backtest_scripts,NLOBS);
    signon connx&x;
    %syslput LOC_BACKTEST_SCRIPTS=&LOC_BACKTEST_SCRIPTS /remote=connx&x;
    %syslput TEST_RUN_NO=&TEST_RUN_NO /remote=connx&x;
    %syslput TEST_ID=Test&x /remote=connx&x;
    %syslput TEST_PGM=&&test&x /remote=connx&x;
    %syslput LOC_TEST_RESULTS=&LOC_BACKTEST_LOGS\Test_&TEST_RUN_NO 
      /remote=connx&x;
    %syslput LOG_LOC=&LOC_BACKTEST_LOGS\Test_&TEST_RUN_NO\&&test&x...log
      /remote=connx&x;
    rsubmit connx&x wait=no ;
      proc printto log="&LOG_LOC"; run;
      options mprint source source2;
      %inc "&LOC_BACKTEST_SCRIPTS\&test_pgm..sas";
    endrsubmit;
    %let waitforlist=&waitforlist connx&x;
  %end;  

  waitfor _all_ &waitforlist;

  %do x=1 %to %to %get_attrn(backtest_scripts,NLOBS);
    signoff connx&x;
  %end;
```

My question - **how do I now connect as a metadata user via the sassrv account?**  I know I could use the `-metauser XXX -metapass XXX` options but I'd rather not embed passwords in my script if possible..

I know (now) that we cannot set up the sassrv account as a metadata user, as it is already in use (SAS General Servers group).  I also need streaming output, so cannot use the workspace server.  I tried using AUTHDOMAIN on my `rsubmit` statement but keep getting:

> ERROR: Retrieving login information based on AuthenticationDomain from
>   the SAS Metadata Server failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, I had to connect via an options statement with metauser / metapass (encoded) credentials.  However, to avoid surfacing these in the code (or in the log) we created a network share that only the system accounts could access..  Then simply %inc'd a text file containing the credentials (with option nosource2 to be sure).

Job done!

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to get the password by amending options  of the program to print the executed macro code with everything included? It could print login/password into the log that can then be accessed by the intruder.

Comment: The text file was %inc'd as the first line of code in the new session..  So the answer is no, not unless one could change the autoexec (or the calling macro)

Comment: Fair enough. How about changing the code file itself? Who has access to the code file? Could they make the %inc second line in code after a few execution option?

Comment: The code files are stored in the usual (default) locations under SASApp\SASEnvironment. If a regular user has modify access to these directories then they could pretty much do anything they like with the sassrv account.. (as well as the batch accounts, as deployed jobs are also stored there)